# Access OS services from Chrome browser JS

Tags: google-chrome

I'm interested in accessing the scanner from within the browser with minimal (or no) download/installs.

I remember reading about a Google project to formalize access to OS services from within Javascript/browser downloads. **Anyone know about that?**

Of course, this would only be used by people whom I have a reputation / relationship with since otherwise the security issues are obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I found the Google project, [Native Client](https://developers.google.com/native-client/overview). However, while it does let C code run on the browser, it is sandboxed and only has limited access to OS services.